# Small example of throw Exception in Haskell

Tags: exception, haskell, error-handling

I have a function in Haskell which works by iterations and which throws an error whenever 3000 iterations are attained.

Recently I discovered **Control.Exception** which allows to define, throw and catch exceptions. I'd like to learn more about it.

I find it difficult to understand (for a Haskell novice like me). That's why I require some help to start.

When 3000 iterations are reached, I'd like to throw my custom exception with a message like "Exception: 3000 iterations". I found `displayException` in the doc, is it the way to go?

So far, here is what I did (this is still a testing phase):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Control.Exception (Exception)

-- for testing purpose
data MyException = ThisException | ThatException
  deriving Show

instance Exception MyException 

data ReachedMax = forall e.Exception e => ReachedMax e

instance Show ReachedMax where
    showsPrec :: Int -> ReachedMax -> ShowS
    showsPrec p (ReachedMax e) = showsPrec p e
```

Sometimes (often) I should say I blindly copy the HLS suggestions. Am I in a right way? Can I continue with my `ReachedMax` constructor?

---

### Background

As some of you know, I'm doing 2D images with Haskell these days. One of them relies on the package with this function which attains 3000 iterations. I'd like to catch these occurences.

Comment: As with your other questions, it's really hard to figure out exactly what you're asking about here, because you only talk about the _solution_ (and only a small part of it) but you don't really give a clear description of what _problem_ you're trying to solve with it.

`ReachedMax` here is a type that can wrap any exception. Is that what you intended? I can't tell from your description. Raising exceptions in Haskell is something you can do only from IO, not in functions, and it looks like you're trying to use it for control flow which would be even more unusual.

Comment: @Cubic I think I'm in a way of a simpler way. But basically, my question is to *identify* the error. For example, if this is the error "Reached 3000 iterations", I want to 1) know this is this error; 2) do not run it if this is this one.

Comment: @Cubic My simpler idea is the following one. I will first return n, the number of iterations, if it is < 3000 that's fine. If it is 3000 I throw the error. But in my other package, the one to draw pictures, I will run the function which return n only. And if n=3000, I will not run the main function. Not easy to deal though with two packages in parallel.

Comment: @Cubic In fact I discovered a nice function, namely `try`. It does what I would want, except that, as you say, it happens in the IO. The ideal function would be like the `tryCatch` in R.

Comment: Can you add an example of how you'd want to _use_ whatever you're imagining? Like, where you want to raise the error / where you want to handle it? Chances are that exceptions are _probably_ not the best way to do it, but it's hard to say without anything concrete.

Comment: @Cubic I'll add an example after I did some progress.

Comment: Can you just use standard/idiomatic Haskell control flow instead? e.g. `iterate f x !! 3000` to run 3000 iterations of function `f` on starting value `x`. More generally, have the iterator produce an infinite list, and the consumer can choose what place(s) in the list it wants to look at. Or, if you don't have control over the producer, could you at least tell us its type/whatever documentation you have on it?

Comment: @DanielWagner Too tired now, I'll show you later. But I won't do it in my real code finallly, it would be too messy and I don't wan't to lose some clarity of a package for the sake of another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an exception is caught by the GHC runtime and halts the program with a message:

```
Exception: blah blah blah
```

the `"blah blah blah"` string is generated by `show` from the `Show` type class.  (For this purpose, the `displayException` method in `Exception` is ignored.)

So, you'll want to define a custom exception type:

```
data ReachedMax = ReachedMax Int
```

give it a `Show` instance for your desired error message:

```
instance Show ReachedMax where
  show (ReachedMax n) = show n ++ " iterations"
```

and make it an instance of the `Exception` class:

```
instance Exception ReachedMax
```

Then, when you `throw` this exception in pure code, the program will be terminated with your custom exception when the relevant expression is evaluated.

For example, if you have a function that tests the Collatz conjecture for an integer and returns the number of iterations required (but throws a custom exception if the number of iterations exceeds 100):

```
collatz :: Int -> Int
collatz n0 = go 0 n0
  where go iter 1 = iter
        go iter n | iter <= 100 = go (iter+1) (step n)
                  | otherwise   = throw $ ReachedMax 100
        step n | even n    = n `div` 2
               | otherwise = 3*n + 1
```

and you run a few tests in GHCi, you should see the desired behavior:

```
λ> collatz 1
0
λ> collatz 10
6
λ> collatz 27
*** Exception: 100 iterations
λ>
```

If you want to catch this exception, you'll need to force evaluation of the pure code in an IO monad, and use `catch` or `try` to catch the desired exception:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do

  -- example using `try`
  r1 <- try @ReachedMax $ evaluate (collatz 27)
  print r1

  -- example using `catch`

  r2 <- evaluate (collatz 27) `catch` (\(_ :: ReachedMax) -> pure (-999))
  print r2
```

In both cases, the catching function needs to be instantiated with the correct `Exception` type, and that type determines which exceptions are caught.

You only need existential exceptions of the form:

```
data SomeSortOfException = forall e. Exception e => SomeSortOfException
```

if you want to create hierarchies of exceptions so that you can catch a branch of the hierarchy containing multiple exception types, instead of catching a specific exception type.

Full code example:

```
module Collatz where

import Control.Exception

data ReachedMax = ReachedMax Int
instance Show ReachedMax where
  show (ReachedMax n) = show n ++ " iterations"
instance Exception ReachedMax

collatz :: Int -> Int
collatz n0 = go 0 n0
  where go iter 1 = iter
        go iter n | iter <= 100 = go (iter+1) (step n)
                  | otherwise   = throw $ ReachedMax 100
        step n | even n    = n `div` 2
               | otherwise = 3*n + 1

main :: IO ()
main = do

  -- example using `try`
  r1 <- try @ReachedMax $ evaluate (collatz 27)
  print r1

  -- example using `catch`

  r2 <- evaluate (collatz 27) `catch` (\(_ :: ReachedMax) -> pure (-999))
  print r2
```

Comment: Amazing demonstration, thanks a lot! I didn't read everything yet, but I will read it and read it again.